# jq: create object from values

Tags: json, jq

I have this input:

```
{ "k1": "v1", "k2": "v2" }
```

I want to get this:

```
{ "v1": "v2" }
```

So, basically, I want to create an object out of another object's values without knowing values but only their keys.

I have tried several `map()` but got no luck. Any hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
{(.k1): .k2}
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Vr3nh_bWMG1)</sup>

Comment: Why we need () around `.k1`, but not `.k2` ?

Comment: @Philippe I don't know, the manual doesn't say why, just that we do

Comment: Most of current days "manuals" are just pesky: no explaination, lots of examples.

Comment: oguz ismail and @EnzoR, It is in the manual: "Key expressions other than constant literals, identifiers, or variable references, need to be parenthesized." If you mean the reasoning behind that language design decision isn't in the reference manual, that has never been in reference manuals and for good reasons. But read-on if you want to find out.

Comment: @Philippe, `{ a: 123 }` means `{ "a": 123 }`. `{ (a): 123 }` is different, as this evaluates the expression `a`. Now, unlike `{ a: 123 }`, `{ .k: 123 }` isn't ambiguous, so they could have allowed it. In other words, one approach the language could have taken is to only require parens when ambiguous. But it instead went with the approach that all expressions other than auto-quoted barewords, quoted literals and vars must use parens.

Comment: There are pros and cons to both. One pro of the approach it takes is that it simplifies the parser (since it doesn't need to check what follows `a` in `{ a ...` to know a is a bareword to auto-quote). It's also much less surprising (since `{ x y: ... }` doesn't work differently than `{ x: ... }`). Another is that it gives it the option of loosening the requirement in future versions without backwards compat issues. Finally, always using parens for expressions is more consistent.